# Will performance and speed improve when retrieving data from a .txt file instead of the Database?

Tags: mysql

I have a site that averages 40k page views a day and I sometimes hit around **100** concurrent users at any given time.

When a user enters the landing page of the site, the database is called to retrieve 6 random items and they are displayed on the webpage.

The database table has nearly **10k rows** and it's using a fairly simplistic statement:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6
```

Even when the landing page is cached, it still calls a .php file that still pulls 6 random items.

The SQL query generally takes around **0.0137 seconds** to execute and currently **isn't using an Index**.

Today I changed it so that the database is called **once per hour** trough a cron job and the results are stored in a **.txt file**. The file is then read when a user hits the landing page and the contents are displayed.

I'm having difficulty measuring a speed improvement as I have no methodology to test with. I'm mainly doing this to try **reduce CPU** usage on the website as a whole.

I have many more live calls that I can convert over to storing in a .txt file but my question is:

**Would it be faster to set up an index on the database and continually call it for each concurrent user or should I proceed with writing to a .txt file once per hour and calling from that**?

Comment: I'm afraid you're barking up the wrong tree.  Of the 40K views, how many hit the landing page?  That times 0.0137s is causing CPU usage??   An elapsed time of 550 seconds, even if all of it was CPU, is nothing to be worried about.  Is your application using persistent connections?  If not, connecting to the database will take more than 0.0137s.

Comment: Given the query, no `WHERE` no `JOIN` and an `ORDER BY rand()`, I don't see anything to index here.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille No I'm not saying it's singularly causing CPU issues but I have many other queries being fired when hitting the landing page and my thinking is that all of them together are possibly causing spikes in usage? No the connections are no persistent, opened to get the results and then closed. It just seemed to me that constantly calling it over and over may be bad? sticky: I'll be reworking the query if I go down that route but I'm trying to figure out if I should go down that route or the .txt file method.

Comment: Forget the text file, MySQL can handle a much bigger load.  You don't need to change a iota to your coding to start using persistent connections.  I believe you just need to add a 'p' before the hostname.  Then you can start to check for slow queries - not this one.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Much appreciated. Persistent connections is the same as Keep-Alive correct? I'll try enabling that and see how I get on in the mean time. I have a max of 50 entry processes on my shared hosting server so I'm hoping that won't restrict it too much.

Comment: There is no relation between the two.  I'm talking about database connections.  Before you can do a "select", you connect to the database and you login.  That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks again @GerardH.Pille . I added persistent connections using p: and it seems to have greatly improved things. Currently at 95 concurrent users and my CPU is hovering around 10-15% usage.

Comment: We aim to please

Comment: @GenesisBits  Please post example of your code with the p: for persistent connection.

Comment: $host = 'p:host';

$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
 $mysqli,
 $host,
 $user,
 $password,
 $db,
 $port
);

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6` requires fetching the entire table, shuffling it, then delivering 6 rows.

Performance is depending on how many rows are hit -- it is 10K *per request* (to get only 6 rows).  Work on shrinking that.

There is no 'perfect' way to fetch 6 rows from a table, but [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) gives 5 pretty-good ways.  See which one fits best in your app for performance improvement.